# Unity application lagging when dragging the application window

Tags: c#, windows, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to set up a game in which moving the game window affects the game world.

When dragging the game window the game lags quite a lot, is there any workaround for this?

I've tried to look it up online but the only 2 threads I found don't have any conclusions:
https://forum.unity.com/threads/standalone-player-pauses-when-dragging-its-window.42315/
https://www.gamedev.net/forums/topic.asp?topic_id=488074

This is the only code I'm running in my application:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using TMPro;
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEngine;

namespace DefaultNamespace
{
    public class PointerMover : MonoBehaviour
    {
        [SerializeField] private RectTransform _pointer;
        [SerializeField] private Canvas _canvas;
        [SerializeField] private TextMeshProUGUI _resolution;
        [SerializeField] private TextMeshProUGUI _windowSize;
        [SerializeField] private TextMeshProUGUI _windowRect;

#if UNITY_EDITOR
        private EditorWindow _window;
#endif
        private Vector2 _monitorSize;
        private IntPtr _windowHandle;
        private RectTransform _canvasRectTransform;

        private void Awake()
        {
#if UNITY_EDITOR
            var gameWindowType = Type.GetType("UnityEditor.GameView,UnityEditor");
            _window = EditorWindow.GetWindow(gameWindowType);
            Debug.Log(_window.position.size);
#endif

            var currentResolution = Screen.currentResolution;
            _monitorSize = new Vector2(currentResolution.width, currentResolution.height);
            _resolution.text = $"Resolution: {currentResolution.width} X {currentResolution.height}";
            _canvasRectTransform = _canvas.GetComponent<RectTransform>();

#if UNITY_STANDALONE_WIN
            _windowHandle = FindWindow(null, "Window Test");
#endif
        }

        private void Update()
        {
#if UNITY_EDITOR

            var windowRect = _window.position;
            var windowCenter = windowRect.center;
            var centerNormalized = new Vector2(windowCenter.x / _monitorSize.x, windowCenter.y / _monitorSize.y);
            var gamePos = centerNormalized * _canvasRectTransform.rect.size;
            gamePos.y *= -1f;

            _pointer.anchoredPosition = gamePos;
            RefreshDebug(windowRect.width, windowRect.height, windowRect.yMin, windowRect.yMax, windowRect.xMin,
                windowRect.xMax, windowCenter, gamePos);
#elif UNITY_STANDALONE_WIN
            GetWindowRect(_windowHandle, out var rect);
            var centerNormalized = new Vector2(rect.Center.x / _monitorSize.x, rect.Center.y / _monitorSize.y);
            var gamePos = centerNormalized * _canvasRectTransform.rect.size;
            gamePos.y *= -1f;
            
            _pointer.anchoredPosition = gamePos;
            RefreshDebug(rect.Width, rect.Height, rect.Top, rect.Bottom, rect.Left, rect.Right, rect.Center, gamePos);
#endif
        }

        private void RefreshDebug(float width, float height, float rectTop, float rectBottom, float rectLeft, float rectRight,
            Vector2 center, Vector2 gamePos)
        {
            _windowSize.text = $"Window Size: {width} X {height}";

            _windowRect.text = $"Top: {rectTop}\n" +
                               $"Bottom: {rectBottom}\n" +
                               $"Left: {rectLeft}\n" +
                               $"Right: {rectRight}\n" +
                               $"Center: ({center.x},{center.y})\n" +
                               $"Game Pos: ({gamePos.x},{gamePos.y})";
        }

#if UNITY_STANDALONE_WIN
        [DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "SetWindowPos")]
        private static extern bool SetWindowPos(IntPtr hwnd, int hWndInsertAfter, int x, int Y, int cx, int cy,
            int wFlags);

        [DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "FindWindow")]
        public static extern IntPtr FindWindow(string className, string windowName);

        [DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "GetWindowRect")]
        static extern bool GetWindowRect(IntPtr hWnd, out WindowRect lpRect);

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        private readonly struct WindowRect
        {
            public readonly int Left;
            public readonly int Top;
            public readonly int Right;
            public readonly int Bottom;

            public int Width => Right - Left;
            public int Height => Bottom - Top;

            public Vector2Int Center => new(Left + Width / 2, Top + Height / 2);
        }

        public static void SetPosition(int x, int y, int resX = 0, int resY = 0)
        {
            SetWindowPos(FindWindow(null, "Binoculars"), 0, x, y, resX, resY, resX * resY == 0 ? 1 : 0);
        }
#endif
    }
}
```